# Validating fields before submitting with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a ordinary button:

```
<button value="finish_with_send" class="finish_with_send">Send</button>
```

I need to validate two fields before submission, so i have replaced this button with following:

```
<a href="javascrtip:void(0)" class="finish_with_send">Send</a>
```

And the validation:

```
$(".finish_with_send").click(function() {
if(!$("#feedback_string").val() || !$("#feedback_title_string").val()) {
        // Validation failed, do something  
    } else {
        // Validation suceeded, submit
    }
})
```

The problem is that i need to submit as done with the previous button where the value came along to recognize submission type:

```
value="finish_with_send"
```

Is there a way that to do this again with jQuery?

Comment: You should probably be subscribing to the `submit` event of the form. Then you can return false if the validation fails.

Comment: You do not need `javascrtip:void(0)` inside the `href`, especially when "javascript" is spelled incorrectly.  You can use a `href="#"` with a `preventDefault()` inside the `click()` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your `<button>` (or go for `<input type="submit">` which I would recommend for greater browser support)... change your javascript like so:

```
$(".finish_with_send").click(function(event) {
if(!$("#feedback_string").val() || !$("#feedback_title_string").val()) {
        event.preventDefault(); //Stop it submitting.
        return false;
    } else {
        return true; //Carry on.
    }
})​
```

And allow your button to `submit` the form like so:

```
<button type="submit" value="finish_with_send" class="finish_with_send">Send</button>
```

`event.preventDefault()` stops the default action of an event firing, in the case of a `<button type="submit">` it's default action is to submit the form.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JUSsf/1/

Comment: The submission does not occur even if its true.

Comment: @JavaCake Did you set your button to `type="submit"` ?

Comment: My bad. I had deleted the `value` which was essential for my backend code. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a submit using `$('#formID').submit()`

If you retain button you can manage the validatiion within a form submit handler. WIll help if user hits "Enter" within form bypassing the button.

```
$('#formID').submit(function() {
    if (!$("#feedback_string").val() || !$("#feedback_title_string").val()) {
        // Validation failed, do something 
        return false; /* stop browser submitting*/
    }

})​
```